# multi validation in cakephp

Tags: validation, cakephp

I Want to use a specific validation for a particular action ,all of them has the same field (username) .

**the result :** It doesn't work, it behaves like if there is no validation at all (i get 'Your profile has been updated.' whatever the length of the username is) .

**note:** some of these actions are in the same view (reg,log) (don't know if that changes anything)

I'm Using Cakephp version 2.5.4 .

---

**User.php :**

```
class User extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'User';
    public  $validate  = array( 'reg' => array('username' => array('rule'=>array('minLength',6)))
                              ,'edit' => array('username' => array('rule'=>array('minLength',4)))
                              ,'log' => array('username' => array('rule'=>array('minLength',2)))
                             );
 }
```

**UsersController.php :**

```
public function edit($id) 
{
    $this->User->validate=$this->User->validate['edit'];
    $info = $this->User->findById($id);
    if ($this->User->validates())   
    {
            if ($this->request->is(array('info','put'))) 
            {
                $this->User->id = $id;
                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) 
                {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your profile has been updated.'));
                }
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your profile.'));
            }   
            if (!$this->request->data) 
            {
                $this->request->data = $info;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go like:

```
public  $myValidationRules  = array(
  'reg' => array(
    'username' => array(
      'minLength' => array(
        'rule' => array('minLength',6)
      )
    )
  ),
  'edit' => array(
    'username' => array(
      'minLength' => array(
        'rule'=>array('minLength',4)
      )
    )
  ),
  'log' => array(
    'username' => array(
      'minLength' => array(
        'rule'=>array('minLength',2)
      )
    )
  )
);
```

and set them in the controller like

```
$this->User->validate = $this->User->myValidationRules['edit'];
```

btw. what should the $this->User->validates() thing to there? - you have just read an already existing user from the db and not set any data - it's useless there!

Comment: It works , vielen dank hmic ,and yes $this->User->validates() doesn't make sense here , but I have a problem shows up now , the validation error message shows up under each username field in the view , even if it was empty .

Comment: to explain more : i have the register and login forms both has a username field, when i write something not allowed in the register username , i get the message twice , in the two forms

Comment: How do you suppose cake distinguishes which username field you mean by an error (or set value) if you got 2 forms of the same model in a view? - it cannot! and i personally think thats no really good idea too. You could however change the model (well field names really) used by the different forms and accomodate for that in the controller later. could do the job, but is rather hacky and not straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

In your user model you are using

```
$this->validation to set your validation rules.
```

where as in controllers edit action you are using

```
$this->User->setValidation;
```

and in your model also please define $validate variable;

```
   public $validate;
```

to set the validation rule.

```
please correct  $this->User->setValidation to $this->User->validation
```

Then it should work.

Comment: I've edited the code above , could you check please if that all i have to do , because it doesn't work yet

Comment: ok in your controller code change this line
 $this->User->validate=$this->User->validation['edit']; to  $this->User->validate=$this->User->validate['edit'];